# ADC (AD7768-4) shows +5 V on all AINx input pins

Tags: adc

I am observing some undesirable behavior with my ADC, an AD7768-4BSTZ. At the four input pins of channels 0 and 1, I measure +5.2 V against GND with a multimeter. On the other hand, I expect a common-mode voltage of approx. +2.5 V. The +5.2 V that I measure is even higher than the supply voltage of +4.98 V.

I am sure the problem is with the ADC and not the frontend because I measure the +5 V at the inputs even when I remove resistors R10-R13 at the inputs.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my circuit? I noticed that I have connected the input pins of channels 2 and 3 (pins 47-50) to GND. Is this possibly the problem?

Attached you will find the schematic of the ADC and the ADC frontend.

Schematic of ADC:
[image: schematic of ADC]

Schematic of ADC frontend:
[image: schematic of ADC frontend]

Please note that there is a wiring error in the second schematic: The potentiometers around the two OP27 operational amplifiers should not be connected to pin 5 but to pin 8 of IC9 and IC10.

Comment: I'm not sure removing R10-R13 and observing 5V at ADC absolves the frontend: the ADC inputs are now floating and it's unclear from its datasheet what to expect at the inputs. Can you check the driving side of of R10-R13 and confirm you see expected signals there?

Comment: You are right, I found the problem: The ADC was alright. However, pin 11 of IC5 was not connected/soldered properly to the PCB which lead to an output voltage going to the rail. Thanks for your comment, at that time I only concentrated on the ADC.